# Javascript callback function firing twice

Tags: javascript

I have four inputs which i would like to add a event to.

I have created a new function on the HTMLCollective

```js
HTMLCollection.prototype.eachOnClick = function(callback){
    var len = this.length
    var j = 0
    for(var i = 0; i < len; i++){
        let elem = this.item(i)
        document.addEventListener('click', () => {
            callback(elem)
        })
    }
}

document.getElementsByClassName('blog-search-filters').eachOnClick(function(elem){
    // if elem.checked do something
    // else do something else
    console.log(elem);
})
```

```html
<div class="blog-search-filters">a</div>
<div class="blog-search-filters">b</div>
```

The problem is that upon clicking on one of these items all four of the input callbacks run twice so the callback function is getting called 8 times.

What am i missing here?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Why are you attaching the `click` handler to the *document*? O.o

Comment: I created working snippet of your code @John and you will probably see the solution yourself now

Comment: its not firing twice. its firing for all

Comment: Do you really want the `HTMLCollection` as `this` in the callback/event handler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seems you need to handle element `click`, not document.

```
HTMLCollection.prototype.eachOnClick = function(callback){
    var len = this.length
    var j = 0
    for(var i = 0; i < len; i++){
        let elem = this.item(i);

        //use elem reference here 
        elem.addEventListener('click', () => {
            callback(elem)
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Doh, missed that completely, i was attaching the click event to the document rather than the element, thank you very much for your help